# Equivalent build-in functions not outputs same values

Tags: php

PHP is known to offer many build-in functions, that do the same thing... This is perhaps more one, but strange,

```php
echo "\nhash = ".hash('crc32', 'My Test');  
     // as guide say "outputs lowercase hexits", hash = c6fd93c1
echo "\nhash from raw = ".bin2hex( hash('crc32','My Test',true) ); 
     // confirm that "hexits" are hexadecimals,  = c6fd93c1
echo "\ncrc32 = ".base_convert( crc32('My Test') , 10, 16);
     // crc32 = c55b6e4  !! not the same
```

there are more than one "standard CRC32"? Why not show the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crc32` function computes same hash as `hash` with `crc32b` does.

```
$ php -r 'echo hash("crc32b", "My Test");' ;echo
0c55b6e4
```

Comment: thanks, you find the equivalent hashes!  For reader: sorry, a better test is "My Test2", that not include a lead "0", and both functions outputs `bdbecdda`.